# Java method that adds a given User to a website's list of users, provided that there are no other users with the same userName

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method called `registerUser(User x)` method that adds a given User to a website's list of users, provided that there are no other users with the same userName. If there are other users with the same userName, then this method does nothing. I'm also trying to make use of the `userWithName(String s)` method I already created, which basically finds and returns the user object with the given name if it is in the list of users, and returns null if it isn't there.

I started the registerUser method, but I'm struggling to continue it. I also don't quite understand where I'm supposed to make use of `userWithName()` in the `registerUser()` function because it's only purpose is to adds a user provided that there are no other users with the same userName.

```java
public String userWithName(String s) {
    for (User u: listofusers) {
        if (u.getUserName().contains(s)) {
            return u.getUserName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public registerUser(User x) {
    for (User u: listofusers) {
        if (!listofusers.contains(u.getUserName) {
            listofusers.add(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to worry about multiple users requesting the same username at the same time? or is this more of an academic exercise?

Comment: it's more of an academic exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, I think you have some bugs in the pasted code. You need to search for strings in a list of strings, and users in a list of users. You can't mix the two up.

```
    public String userWithName(String s) {
        //gets a list of String usernames from list of users
        List<String> usernames = listofusers.stream().map(User::getUserName).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (usernames.contains(s)) {
            return s;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public registerUser(User x){
        if(!listofusers.contains(x)) {
            listofusers.add(x);
        }
    }
```

If the Java 8 Stream nonsense to get a list of usernames is intimidating, this is a perfectly viable alternative.

```
public String userWithName(String s) {
    String username = null;
    for(User u: listofusers) {
        if(u.getUsername().equals(s)) {
            username = s;
        }
    }
    return username;
}
```

If this does not answer the question, please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
public registerUser(User x){
    if(userWithName(x.getUserName() == null) {
          listofusers.add(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String userWithName(User X){
    for(User u: listofusers){
        if(u.getUserName().contains(X.getUserName()){
            return u.getUserName();
        }
    }
    /* that means there is not a user of this name, so we add it*/
    registerUser(X);
}

public registerUser(User x){
     listofusers.add(x);
}
```